# Error opening new searcher on solr core initialization

Tags: java, solr, lucene

We have setup solr with multiple cores. But while changing frequently in schema file. Solr core suddenly stops working with Exception `org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher`. Also these cores went missing from Core selector and solr list

I have tried multiple things like created new core and copy index to new core. But new core also ran into this exception.

[image]

Comment: The Solr log should show you the complete exception, and hopefully point you to the underlying cause of the error. You can find the logs under the Solr installation directory (usually - depending on your configuration)

Comment: @MatsLindh solr logs showing error `cannot change DocValues type from SORTED to SORTED_SET for field solr tagName` but changing default fieldType for tagName is not making any difference. I also tried to reload core after changing field types

Comment: This means that after indexing data the field type has changed from being single valued to be multivalued (i.e. `multiValued="true"`). This change won't work with docValues enabled for the field (both are true by default).

Comment: Yes SORTED_SET is set when multivalue = true but how but how can I fixed this issue if solr core is not initializing and went missing from list.

Comment: Fix the field definition in the schema and then bring the server up / reload the core after changing the definition to not be multivalued any longer.